# JSON Build Object Inside an Array with Postgress

Tags: javascript, sql, json, postgresql, drag-and-drop

I am working to build a drag and drop feature for a client project and need my data to look like this:

`[ [Array(10)], [Array(5)], [Array(5)], [Array(5)], [Array(5)] ]`

Where each array will look like this (each of these are representing patients):

`[ {id: 1, reccomendations: [array] } ]`

The recommendations array, one level deeper, will look like this:

`["providerName1", "providerName2", "providerName3"]`

My database is set up as such:

**Patient Table**

```
+----+-----------+
| id | bucket_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |     1     |
|  2 |     2     |
|  3 |     3     |
|  4 |     4     |
|  5 |     5     |
|  6 |     6     |
|  7 |     2     |
|  8 |     3     |
|  9 |     4     |
| 10 |     5     |
+----+-----------+
```

**patient_provider Table**
provider_id references provider.id
patient_id references patiend.id

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | provider_id | patient_id  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |       1     |      1      |
|  2 |       7     |      1      |
|  3 |       3     |      1      |
|  4 |       1     |      2      |
|  5 |       8     |      3      |
|  6 |       7     |      3      |
|  7 |       3     |      4      |
|  8 |       2     |      5      |
|  9 |      11     |      5      |
| 10 |       1     |      6      |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

**Provider Table**
provider_id references provider.id
patient_id references patiend.id

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | provider_id | patient_id  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |       1     |      1      |
|  2 |       7     |      1      |
|  3 |       3     |      1      |
|  4 |       1     |      2      |
|  5 |       8     |      3      |
|  6 |       7     |      3      |
|  7 |       3     |      4      |
|  8 |       2     |      5      |
|  9 |      11     |      5      |
| 10 |       1     |      6      |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

**Provider Table**
There are more rows and columns than this, but this is the only column I need

```
+----+-----------+
| id |  program  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |   blue    |
|  2 |    red    |
|  3 |   green   |
|  4 |   yellow  |
|  5 |    pink   |
|  6 |   teal    |
+----+-----------+
```

I've run this:

```
SELECT "patient".id, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT("provider".program)) as providers FROM "patient"
  LEFT JOIN "patient_provider" ON "patient_provider".patient_id = "patient".id
  LEFT JOIN "provider" ON "provider".id = "patient_provider".provider_id
  GROUP BY "patient".id
  ORDER BY "patient".id ASC;
```

Which will get me the array of providers per patient.

I have also run this:

```
SELECT JSON_AGG("patient") as patient FROM "patient"
WHERE "patient".bucket_id =1;
```

With this, I can get all the buckets/columns and the patients that belong in those columns.

I haven't been able to find a way to combine the two into the data structure that I need. I've done some reading on JSON Build Objects - would this be the way to go? How would I do that?
I am also open to doing this workflow on the server-side, using a function to splice and manually get me the data structure that I need...if that is the better way to do it. If you think that that is the way to go, how would I do it?

I'll buy coffee for whoever can help me with this! I'd love to make my clients' day by building this feature out for them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your case with the following statements

```
create table patient (id serial, bucket_id int);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (1);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (2);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (3);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (4);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (5);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (6);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (2);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (3);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (4);
insert into patient (bucket_id) values (5);

create table patient_provider (id serial, provider_id int, patient_id int);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (1,1);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (7,1);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (3,1);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (1,2);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (8,3);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (7,3);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (3,4);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (2,5);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (11,5);
insert into patient_provider (provider_id, patient_id) values (1,6);

create table provider (id serial, program varchar);
insert into provider (program) values ('blue');
insert into provider (program) values ('red');
insert into provider (program) values ('green');
insert into provider (program) values ('yellow');
insert into provider (program) values ('pink');
insert into provider (program) values ('teal');
```

Now, taking your first query, and using the `json_build_object` function, you can achieve the `{id: 1, reccomendations: [array] }` (the external array is not really needed). The query is the below

```
SELECT json_build_object('id',"patient".id, 'reccomendations', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT("provider".program))) as obj FROM "patient"
LEFT JOIN "patient_provider" ON "patient_provider".patient_id = "patient".id
LEFT JOIN "provider" ON "provider".id = "patient_provider".provider_id
GROUP BY "patient".id
ORDER BY "patient".id ASC
```

And the result is

```
                          obj
-------------------------------------------------------
 {"id" : 1, "reccomendations" : ["blue","green",null]}
 {"id" : 2, "reccomendations" : ["blue"]}
 {"id" : 3, "reccomendations" : [null]}
 {"id" : 4, "reccomendations" : ["green"]}
 {"id" : 5, "reccomendations" : ["red",null]}
 {"id" : 6, "reccomendations" : ["blue"]}
 {"id" : 7, "reccomendations" : [null]}
 {"id" : 8, "reccomendations" : [null]}
 {"id" : 9, "reccomendations" : [null]}
 {"id" : 10, "reccomendations" : [null]}
(10 rows)
```

Now, if you want to aggregate the above results, you can do so with the `json_agg` function. This is the overall code

```
With single_objects as (
    SELECT json_build_object('id',"patient".id, 'reccomendations', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT("provider".program))) as obj FROM "patient"
      LEFT JOIN "patient_provider" ON "patient_provider".patient_id = "patient".id
      LEFT JOIN "provider" ON "provider".id = "patient_provider".provider_id
      GROUP BY "patient".id
      ORDER BY "patient".id ASC
      )
select json_agg(obj) from single_objects
```

and result

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   json_agg
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"id" : 1, "reccomendations" : ["blue","green",null]}, {"id" : 2, "reccomendations" : ["blue"]}, {"id" : 3, "reccomendations" : [null]}, {"id" : 4, "reccomendations" : ["green"]}, {"id" : 5, "reccomendations" : ["red",null]}, {"id" : 6, "reccomendations" : ["blue"]}, {"id" : 7, "reccomendations" : [null]}, {"id" : 8, "reccomendations" : [null]}, {"id" : 9, "reccomendations" : [null]}, {"id" : 10, "reccomendations" : [null]}]
(1 row)
```

If you really need the extra array encapsulation for each id, you just need to add a `json_build_array` function to the `json_build_object` call mentioned above. Full query

```
With single_objects as (
    SELECT json_build_array(json_build_object('id',"patient".id, 'reccomendations', ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT("provider".program)))) as obj FROM "patient"
      LEFT JOIN "patient_provider" ON "patient_provider".patient_id = "patient".id
      LEFT JOIN "provider" ON "provider".id = "patient_provider".provider_id
      GROUP BY "patient".id
      ORDER BY "patient".id ASC
      )
select json_agg(obj) from single_objects
```

End result

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             json_agg
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [[{"id" : 1, "reccomendations" : ["blue","green",null]}], [{"id" : 2, "reccomendations" : ["blue"]}], [{"id" : 3, "reccomendations" : [null]}], [{"id" : 4, "reccomendations" : ["green"]}], [{"id" : 5, "reccomendations" : ["red",null]}], [{"id" : 6, "reccomendations" : ["blue"]}], [{"id" : 7, "reccomendations" : [null]}], [{"id" : 8, "reccomendations" : [null]}], [{"id" : 9, "reccomendations" : [null]}], [{"id" : 10, "reccomendations" : [null]}]]
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'll actually buy you coffee! Message me :)

Comment: Ahahahah, no worries, happy to be helpful!

Comment: Months later, I built another project and had to refer back to this awesome query. +++